# Batting average MySQL query

Tags: mysql

You may need some knowledge of cricket to help with this one. Given the following table, would this query produce this result?

```
Table: batsmen
batsmanname | runsscored | howout
Colin       | 10         | bowled
Colin       | 20         | caught
Steve       | 10         | bowled
Steve       | 20         | not out

SELECT batsmanname, SUM(runsscored) / COUNT(howout) AS battingavg
FROM batsmen 
WHERE howout <> 'not out' 
GROUP BY batsmananme

Result:
batsmanname | battingavg
Colin       | 15
Steve       | 30
```

Comment: *"would this query produce this result?"* - did you try it? (It looks plausible, but `AS` seems to be in the wrong place)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should produce the results that you want:

```
SELECT b1.name, SUM(b1.runsscored) / b2.NumOut as bat_avg
FROM batsmen b1
INNER JOIN
(
  select name, COUNT(howout) as NumOut
  from batsmen
  WHERE howout <> 'not out' 
  GROUP BY name
) b2
  ON b1.name = b2.name
GROUP BY b1.name
```

See [SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5f835/12)

Comment: Thanks. What do b1 and b2 refer to?

Comment: They are table aliases for the batsmen table.  I am using b1/b2 to reference where the data is coming from